# SceneBuilder and settings.xml

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gluon

Does the latest version of SceneBuilder read the settings.xml file in the default Maven repository? I have my .m2 folder in a non standard location but when I asked SceneBuilder to find a repository to add a custom control it could not find anything although settings.xml contained the new .m2 location. I was able to add the jar directory.

Comment: There is an .m2 folder in the default location with a settings.xml file but otherwise this location is empty.

Comment: Sadly for you there is a [TO-DO](https://github.com/gluonhq/scenebuilder/blob/98f692b092c6fc4b2724686f99d9242701aa68c9/app/src/main/java/com/oracle/javafx/scenebuilder/app/util/AppSettings.java#L181) exactly for what you are looking for. Time to contribute?

Comment: I’ll add it to my TO-DO list.